# hp pavilion dm4-1160us black screen while booting

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 on hp pavilion dm4-1160US, it first boots by showing a purple screen and goes into a black screen.

What could be happening please?

Answer (score 0):

when the purple screen showing press enter and its setup 9.10.Before installition start press F6 and there is a new menu.In the menu select "nomodeset" and setup ubuntu normally.